# Improve web app/rest-api performance by setting BasicDataSource property testOnBorrow=false , is it risky?

Tags: java, spring, performance, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

It seems like we could improve our performance by setting `testOnBorrow=false` on org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource. But what are the risks?

The [default setting](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html) is true.

So, with the defaults, every single time a connection is retrieved from the connection pool a validation query is executed against the db to test if it is valid. While that query may run quickly (typically "select 1" is the query). It still involves sending data to the db (often on another server) and reading the result back. It takes time, maybe only 50ms, but still, why incur that if it is not necessary?

To improve performance I'm considering setting `testOnBorrow=false, testOnReturn=true, testOnCreate =true, testWhileIdle=true`. Instead of the defaults.

So with this setup it seems like the risk is that a connection could "go bad" and your db query fails. But why would that happen? Especially with the testOnReturn and testWhileIdle it seems risk would be minimal. What could cause a connection to go bad in this setup?

Comment: Anything. From a functional perspective you must be prepared for a connection closing at any time without a visible reason. This also means that checking a connection when you borrow it is useless in a functional sense. But from a performance point of view what you have to ask is this: how likely is it that a connection will go down between the last idle test and the first query? This will depend on a lot of things. And also, how much overhead will the continuous idle testing cause vs. the once per borrow.

Answer (score 1):

Please mind that correctness and performance are both desired attributes. In practice stale connections are real concern and we often have to engage DBAs/System Admin for assistance. As implied by you, connection corruption should not happen, but do occur due to network conditions.

Using a validation query helps quickly identify a corrupt connection and discard it from pool. This will eventually allow a new connection object to be added to the pool. This automated recovery process is more than desirable IMO.